# Number of ways to put $k$ different numbers in $n$ place

Tags: permutations, combinations

I am working on problem which simplifies to the following which I can't solve. Please help.

There are $n$ places and I want to put number $1$ through $k$ in these places. Each place must have one number, and each number has to appear at least once. Of course, $n\geq k$.

For example, if $n=3$ and $k=2$, then there are 6 ways:

- 112
- 121
- 122
- 211
- 212
- 221

What is the total number of ways of doing this?

Comment: Can a number appear more than once?  For example, could 1 be put in two different places?

Comment: Yes, each number can appear more than once.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this.  Notice that Antoine's answer can also be written as $k^n-\binom{k}{1}(k-1)^n+\binom{k}{2}(k-2)^n-\binom{k}{3}(k-3)^n+\cdots+(-1)^{k-1}\binom{k}{k-1}1^n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try with inclusion-exclusion principle. For $1\leq i \leq k$ define $A_i$ as the set of all arrangements in which number $i$ does not appear and find $|(A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_k)^c|$.

Just for fun, the number you get can also be expressed in terms of Stirling numbers of the second kind, since it equals $S(n,k)k!$. Also, this is the number of surjective maps from a set with $n$ elements to a set with $k$ elements.

So, let's compute it. It is obvious that

- all $k\choose 1$ sets $A_{i}$ ($A_1$, $A_2$, $\dots$, $A_n$) are of the same size,
- all $k\choose 2$ sets $ A_{i_1} \cap A_{i_2}$, $i_1<i_2$, are of the same size

  $\vdots$
- all of the $k\choose k$ ($=1$) sets $A_{i_1}\cap \dots \cap A_{i_{k}}$, $i_1 <\cdots < i_{k}$, are of the same size

Therefore, we just have to compute $a_i = |A_1 \cap \dots\cap A_i|$ for all $1\leq i\leq k$, which is quite simple. Since we can put any of the numbers $i+1$, $\cdots$, $k-1$ and  $k$ (that is $k-i$ numbers) in the first, in the second, ... , and in  the $n$-th place, we conlcude that
$$a_i = (k-i)^n\text{.}$$

Thus, by inclusion-exclusion prinicple, we have

$$|(A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_k)^c| = k^n -\sum_{i = 1}^k (-1)^{i+1} {k\choose i}a_i = \sum_{i=1}^k (-1)^i{k\choose i} (k-i)^n\text{,}$$
which can be simplified to
$$|(A_1 \cup \cdots \cup A_k)^c| = \sum_{i=0}^k (-1)^{i}{k\choose i} (k-i)^n\text{.}$$

Comment: Dear Antoine, sorry for the previous comment (now erased): the edited  version of the question shows that you were correct in your interpretation. I have upvoted  you, of course!

Comment: Everyone except for everybody's boss is wrong from time to time.

Comment: Dear Antoine: I'm amazed that you know my wife and me so well  :-)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is $$\binom{n}{k}k!$$ Indeed there are $\binom{n}{k}$ ways to choose the $k$ places among the $n$ available ones and for each such choice you can lodge your $k$ numbers in $k!$ ways in the $k$ elected places.

**Edit**
This is an answer to a previous version of the question, which in my interpretation meant that you couldn't repeat numbers nor have two different numbers in one place.

Comment: Sorry that my expression was not very clear before. Each place must have one number. Please see the edited post.

Comment: (This is the way I first interpreted the question also.)

Comment: I have edited my answer, taking Patrick's comment and edit in consideration.